# Парсинг выдаёт только одну картинку

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Вот код на `python`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# переменная показывающая номер домена
a = 0

def parse_img(g):
    for i in range(g):
        global a
        a += 1
        url = 'https://www.1zoom.ru/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0/t2/'
        HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

        html = requests.get(url + str(a), headers = HEADERS )
        print(html.url)
        html = html.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        div_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'suda'})
        
        img_tags = [div.find('img') for div in div_tags]

        url_img = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]
        return url_img
    
# Парсинг первого домена
print(parse_img(1))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате с сайта парсится только одна картинка вместо всех картинок на сайте

Вывод:

```
https://www.1zoom.ru/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0/t2/1/
['https://s1.1zoom.ru/prev2/581/Ginger_color_Cute_Kittens_580356_300x214.jpg']
```

И у меня вопрос, как сделать, чтобы парсились все картинки с доменов сайта, а не только одна?

Comment: Меня этот момент смущает: `div_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'suda'})`, элементы с `id` уникальны в документе. А чтобы парсить все картинки нужно и искать все картинки, например: `url_img = [img['src'] for img in soup.select('img[src]')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал парсер:

- Использовал парсер "из коробки": `html.parser`
- Поиск картинок сделан через css-селектор
- `#suda` – поиск элемента с `id="suda"`
- `.ph` – элемент с `class="ph"`
- `>` – указание, что элемент справа является прямым ребенком элемента слева. Т.е. `.ph > a` говорит, что у элемента с класом `ph` есть вложенный элемент `<a>`
- `img[src]` – поиск `<img>` у которого будет аттрибут `src`
- Небольшой рефакторинг

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f16c2de6f364876dd531c11e357f51d84a9fe18e/html_parsing/www_1zoom_ru__%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5__%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0.py#L11):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_imgs(page: int) -> list:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    }
    url = f'https://www.1zoom.ru/Животные/Котята/t2/{page}'

    rs = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

    return [img['src'] for img in root.select('#suda .ph > a > img[src]')]

# Парсинг первой страницы
imgs = get_imgs(1)
print(len(imgs), imgs)
# 30 ['https://s1.1zoom.ru/prev2/581/Ginger_color_Cute_Kittens_580356_300x214.jpg', ...

# Парсинг второй страницы
imgs = get_imgs(2)
print(len(imgs), imgs)
# 30 ['https://s1.1zoom.ru/prev2/570/Cats_White_background_Kittens_569316_300x200.jpg', ...
```